# convert PIL.Image to IOBase class

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, aiogram, bytesio

I have a bot that creates a qr code and I want it to send qr code to the user without saving it to the hard drive

I create qr code like this:

```
import qrcode
qr_code_img = qrcode.make('some data')   # in handler used # qrcode.make(message.text')
print(type(qr_code_img))                 # <class 'qrcode.image.pil.PilImage'>
print(type(qr_code_img.get_image()))     # <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
```

I think I need to get `<class '_io.BytesIO'>`

with information about qr code

`class aiogram.types.input_file.InputFile(path_or_bytesio: Union[str, IOBase, Path, _WebPipe],       filename=None, conf=None)`

docs: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/types/input_file.html

```
file = InputFile(path_or_bytesio = ?)    #need to convert qr code to something
await bot.send_photo(chat_id = message.from_user.id, photo = file)
```

thanks a lot

```
qr_code_img = qrcode.make(message.text)
await bot.send_photo(chat_id = message.from_user.id, photo = qr_code_img)
```

if I just send a qrcode i'll get error

`````
TypeError: Can not serialize value type: <class 'qrcode.image.pil.PilImage'>
 headers: {}
 value: <qrcode.image.pil.PilImage object at 0x000001C741E4CE10> ````
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't great, but I think you just want to save to a `BytesIO` object.

Something like:

```
from io import BytesIO

import qrcode
import aiogram

def make_qrcode(text):
    buf = BytesIO()
    qrcode.make(text).save(buf, format='PNG')
    buf.seek(0)
    return aiogram.types.InputFile(buf, "qrcode.png")

bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.from_user.id, photo=make_qrcode("example text"))
```

Would hopefully do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

For aiogram 3.0 it works a bit differently:

```
import qrcode
import qrcode.image.svg
from io import BytesIO
from aiogram.types import BufferedInputFile


def make_qr(url: str) -> BufferedInputFile:
    # Better use BytesIO as context manager
    with BytesIO() as buffer:
        image = qrcode.make(url)
        # Don't use format kwarg - it is not useful anymore. 
        # If you need specified format better choose it in make()
        image.save(buffer)
        # Following command sets cursor to 0 position in the buffer
        buffer.seek(0)
        # To transform _io.Bytes to bytesarray you need to use read()
        file_to_send = BufferedInputFile(buffer.getvalue(), "qrcode.svg")
    # *EDITED* better use BytesIO.getvalue() than BytesIO.read()
    # Sure, you can return BufferedInputFile with not using variable
    return file_to_send
```

`InputFile` is not required for direct use anymore. Now you need to use child classes like `BufferedInputFile`.